# Schematron - Element validation based on its position

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, schematron

I am using Schematron to do some business rule validations. My xml data looks like:

```
<labtests>  
    <test>
        <observation>
            <code code="TT900" name="NMCK"/>
            <outcome value="074042"/>
        </observation>            
    </test>

    <test>
        <observation>
            <code code="TT500" name="LVCT"/>
            <outcome value="852417"/>
        </observation>            
    </test>
    <test>
        <observation>
            <code code="TT500" name="LVCT"/>
            <outcome value="36542"/>
        </observation>            
    </test>
    <test>
        <observation>
            <code code="TT100" name="GVMC"/>
            <outcome value="874541"/>
        </observation>            
    </test>
    <test>
        <observation>
            <code code="TT500" name="LVCT"/>
            <outcome value="369521"/>
        </observation>            
    </test>
</labtests>
```

The current context is set to `labtests/test/observation` like below:

```
<iso:rule context="labtests/test/observation">
    <!--perform all validations here-->


</iso:rule>
```

I want to perform some special business validation checks on the `<outcome>` node for the first `<observation>` block having `code/@code="TT500"`.

I think I can use the following expression to get the position of first intended `<observation>` block

```
count(../../test/observation/code[@code="TT500"]/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```

but I don't know how to compare this position with the node in the current context to perform special validation.

**UPDATE:**

For the sake of simplicity let's assume that the special validation to be performed in this case is that the length of `outcome/@value` must be greater than or equal to 6. i.e.

```
<iso:report test="not(string-length(outcome/@value) >= 6">
    outcome/@value should have at least 6 characters for the first TT500 observation
</iso:report>
```

Comment: Please explain what your assertion or rule should do, which nodes it is concerned with, and what situation it should assert or report (i.e. what is allowed and what isn't). Even better: show **two** documents, one which is valid and a second one which is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Schematron document does exactly what you have asked. There is no real difference between `assert` and `report`, you can invert any rule to fit both.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt2">
    <pattern>
        <rule context="observation[code/@code = 'TT500' and not(preceding::observation[code/@code = 'TT500'])]">
            <assert test="string-length(outcome/@value) ge 6"> outcome/@value should have at least 6 characters for the first TT500 observation </assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>
```

When the following (invalid) XML document is validated with this SCH rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="sample.sch" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<labtests>  
    <test>
        <observation>
            <code code="TT900" name="NMCK"/>
            <outcome value="07442"/>
        </observation>            
    </test>
    <test>
        <observation>
            <code code="TT500" name="LVCT"/>
            <outcome value="85417"/>
        </observation>            
    </test>
    <test>
        <observation>
            <code code="TT500" name="LVCT"/>
            <outcome value="36542"/>
        </observation>            
    </test>           
</labtests>
```

A Schematron processor will issue a warning along the lines of

```
E [ISO Schematron] outcome/@value should have at least 6 characters for the first TT500 observation
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Never knew that filters can be applied in the `<rule>` node. Silly me.

Comment: @AJQarshi  You are welcome. The value inside `sch:rule` can in fact be any [XSLT pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-pattern), which is only a subset of all possible expressions.